# how to make a device client or sender if he press connect button

Tags: java, android, wifi-direct

I am using `wifip2p` `manager` to send file from one device to another.
Always same device become client or in other word, other device always remain group owner who will always receive `data`.

I have tried below code to make send and receive `data`.

```
void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo info) {

        this.info = info;
        this.getView().setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        // The owner IP is now known.
        TextView view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.group_owner);
        view.setText(getResources().getString(R.string.group_owner_text) + ((info.isGroupOwner == true) ? getResources().getString(R.string.yes) : getResources().getString(R.string.no)));

        // InetAddress from WifiP2pInfo struct.
        view = (TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.device_info);
        view.setText("Group Owner IP - " + info.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());

        // After the group negotiation, we assign the group owner as the file
        // server. The file server is single threaded, single connection server
        // socket.
        if (info.groupFormed && info.isGroupOwner) {
            new FileServerAsyncTask(getActivity(), mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text)).execute();
        } else if (info.groupFormed) {
            // The other device acts as the client. In this case, we enable the
            // get file button.
            mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_start_client).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            ((TextView) mContentView.findViewById(R.id.status_text)).setText(getResources().getString(R.string.client_text));
        }
        // hide the connect button
        mContentView.findViewById(R.id.btn_connect).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

These are the resources you need to check for how to implement your solution:

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/969c243/docs/html/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.jd

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo

**Keep in mind:**

`<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />`

(permission needed to find nearby peers)

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/wifi/WpsInfo.html#PBC

`WpsInfo.PBC` is deprecated only after api 28, so you need to set it to WifiP2pConfig instance in able to connect to the channel

Comment: sir check this link i have asked this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/57834846/9657093 please help me i am finding the right solution for this problem since last 15 days