# How to make own device client or sender

Tags: android, wifip2p

I am developing a sharing app where i am using wifip2p framework to connect two devices and one is sender and other is receiver. And the problem that i am facing is that who would be sender and who would be receiver get selected automatically.

I am using below code to connect to devices.

```
/**
 * @param device to connect
 */
@Override
public void connect(WifiP2pDevice device) {
    WifiP2pConfig config = new WifiP2pConfig();
    config.groupOwnerIntent = 0;
    config.deviceAddress = device.deviceAddress;
    config.wps.setup = WpsInfo.PBC;
    manager.connect(channel, config, new WifiP2pManager.ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSuccess() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(int reason) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Connect failed. Retry.",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

and to delete previous created groups i used below code.

```
/**
 *  @deletePersistentGroups delete all created groups
 */

private void deletePersistentGroups(){
    try {
        Method[] methods = WifiP2pManager.class.getMethods();
        for (int i = 0; i < methods.length; i++) {
            if (methods[i].getName().equals("deletePersistentGroup")) {
                // Delete any persistent group
                for (int netid = 0; netid < 32; netid++) {
                    methods[i].invoke(manager, channel, netid, null);
                }
            }
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

***this onConnectionInfoAvailable function is trigger when both device connect successfully and i am facing the problem i.e. if i click on connect button from device 1 , sometimes it acts as sender or sometimes receiver what i want to achieve is that  device 1 must always be sender and other device receiver***

```
  /**
     * @param wifiP2pInfo connection information after device connected to desire device
     */
    @Override
    public void onConnectionInfoAvailable(WifiP2pInfo wifiP2pInfo) {
        if (wifiP2pInfo.groupFormed && wifiP2pInfo.isGroupOwner ) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Owner", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            new FileServerAsyncTask(this).execute();
        }
        else if (wifiP2pInfo.groupFormed){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Client", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), FileTransferService.class);
            serviceIntent.setAction(FileTransferService.ACTION_SEND_FILE);
            serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_FILE_PATH, path);
            serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_ADDRESS, wifiP2pInfo.groupOwnerAddress.getHostAddress());
            serviceIntent.putExtra(FileTransferService.EXTRAS_GROUP_OWNER_PORT, 8988);
            startService(serviceIntent);
        }
    }
```

Comment: for what reason do you need to know who is server and client?

Comment: that was the old question and now i am facing this problem i.e  who would be sender and who would be receiver get selected automatically.

Comment: why do you care? did you manage to create a connection? https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct#connect

Comment: sir look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/57834846/12034846 i have tried every thing

Comment: in documentation they mentioned " Note: If all the devices in a network support Wi-Fi Direct, you can use the connect() method on each device because the method then creates the group and selects a group owner automatically. "

Comment: have you followed this sample: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo

Comment: yes sir i have followed this https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo too

Comment: now update your code and show us which part doesnt work

Comment: sir everything works fine but the problem is that when i connect or press connect button from device 1 both device connect successfull but the group owner get selected automatically i.e. who will be sender or receiver get selected automatically

Comment: well this was the previous question that you asked, and now looks like you are asking it again (duplicate). why do you need to know who is the sender and who is the receiver?, shows us in the question what would you like to achieve with the sender and the receiver? Try to explain what you are doing, you don't need to ask multiple questions

Comment: check my updated question

Comment: how to achieve what you want I dont know, but you still didn't answer why do you need to know that? what are you going to do with it?